# Query to delete data before 90 days in 100-100 batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @DELETED_ROWS INT;
SET @DELETED_ROWS = 100

WHILE (@DELETED_ROWS > 0)
BEGIN
    WITH cte AS
    (
         SELECT
             DATEADD(DAY, -90, UPDATEDDATE) AS date, audit_id 
         FROM
             auditdata 
    ) 
    DELETE TOP (100) 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE audit_id <= (SELECT MIN(audit_id) + 100 FROM cte) 

    SET @DELETED_ROWS = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: This is getting delete with the above query however performance wise its taking too much time to execute. Can someone help me to optimize this or any other query for better performance

Comment: Please help me with this by using while loop.
we are deleting data on date column and we do not have index there
Need to delete on audit_ID column.

Comment: how many rows are get deleted during each loop

Comment: 100-100 batches

Comment: Please [edit] your comments into the question, because as it stands there is no question.

Answer (score 2):

So you're splitting the delete into batches.
Then you might want to commit the batch transactions.

And the delete statement can be simplified.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
DECLARE @DELETED_ROWS INT = 1;
 
WHILE @DELETED_ROWS > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
  DELETE TOP (100)
  FROM auditdata
  WHERE UPDATEDDATE < DATEADD(DAY, -90, GetDate());
 
  SET @DELETED_ROWS = @@ROWCOUNT;
 
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Comment: For a single `DELETE` there is no point using `BEGIN` `COMMIT`. Within each transactiono only one `DELETE` is being executed

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Rows INT = 100
WHILE (@Rows=100)
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (100)
    FROM auditdata
    WHERE 
        UPDATEDDATE<DATEADD(DAY,-90, GETDATE())
    
     SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
    
 END
```